# I want to write a regular expression to match different styles of telephone number

Tags: python, regex

I want to search all the phone numbers in a text. In this text, I found 4 different formats of phone number:

```
1234567890
123-456-7890
123 456 7890
(123)456-7890
```

I wrote a regex pattern and try it in python:

```
\(?\d{3}[\)\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}
```

This pattern works, I can use it to search all the phone numbers from the text. But, it also matches some wrong format such as "(1234567890", "123)456-7890" and more wrong formats. I am new to regex. Could you please help me to fix this problem? Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Ugh, you have a bad word in your text.

Comment: Try to use [this tool](https://regexr.com/). It's very helpful to work with regular expressions.

Comment: Don't try to match all patterns at once. Make regexes for each and loop over the patterns and see if any match. The hyphens and spaces ones could obviously be combined, though.

Comment: @ André Pacheco, @Harvery and U9-Forward, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that works that you can start with.

```
numbers = """
1234567890
123-456-7890
123 456 7890
(123)456-7890
(1234567890
 123)456-7890
"""

import re

patterns = [
    r'\d{10}',
    r'\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{4}',
    r'\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}',
]
patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]
results = []
for line in numbers.split('\n'):
    for p in patterns:
        match = p.match(line)
        if match:
            results.append(line)
```

Comment: After some research, I found the following pattern works: r"(?P<left>\\()?\d{3}(?(left)\\)\d{3}-\d{4}|(?P<delimiter>[-\s]?)\d{3}(?P=delimiter)\d{4})"

Comment: @StevenLi Use a verbose regex to document it in your code.